# Load javascript via jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery %Json function to load a javascriptfile.js asynchronously?

Comment: Rephrase? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to load a load a Json request with an embeded js file.

Comment: to load another js file with a json response.

Answer (score 4):

`$.getScript("/path/to/script.js")`

Comment: but what should the json response be?

Comment: There shouldn't be a JSON response. You asked to load a script, not process a piece of JSON data.

Comment: i need the script.js embeded in the Json response, it gets a different file depending on response.

Comment: the js file is part of the response

Comment: That sounds decidedly dirty, but generate a script element and a text node containing the data extracted from the JSON. append the text to the script and the script to the body.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load an external JavaScript file then you should use Ramon's suggestions.

But if you're for sure that the response format is JSON you could use the [getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback) which loads JSON data using an HTTP GET request.

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, [data], [callback] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's pure JavaScript coding that downloads a JavaScript file and put it in the header page itself (if you plan to have a very lightweight page that is instantaneously visible then download JavaScript file in the background) :

```
var getheadTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
setjs = document.createElement('script');
setjs.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
getheadTag.appendChild(setjs);
setjs.text = x.responseText;
```